# Forecasting using multiple regression

Tags: multiple-regression, forecasting

I have data in the form given below, and I want to perform forecasting using multiple regression. I found definition of multiple regression from this link: http://otexts.com/fpp/5/1/ . I have these questions: **(1)** Can we forecast value of Y (the dependent variable) based on the given values of the independent variables (X1 and X2), as in below table? or it is mandatory to have previous values of Y along with X1 and X2 to forecast the future value of Y, **(2)** I want to forecast the value of Y at T8, by providing two inputs, i.e., value of Y_at_T8 = forecast(X1=22, X2=33), how to proceed on that? , **(3)** Is it mandatory for multiple regression that Time must be in fixed intervals, can it increase in varying intervals?

**Time | X1 | X2**

T1   | 23 | 33
T2   | 43 | 22
T3   | 42 | 44
T4   | 33 | 32
T5   | 43 | 11
T6   | 55 | 21
T7   | 23 | 42

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use regression here, then check all the assumptions of the model carefully after fitting. The errors should be uncorrelated for example. Your $Y$ here is time dependent and it is very likely that some assumptions are violated.  I suggest to use time series regression with regressors as $X1$ and $X2$ instead of multiple regression. See Arima for example in package [forecast](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf). For this approach, depending on the model, it may use the previous $Y$'s to forecast. To answer your questions:

1) Yes you can. You use the previous values of $Y$, $X1$ and $X2$ to fit your model. Then you plug in the new values for $Xi$'s i.e. $X1=22$, $X2=33$ to forecast $Y_{T8}$.

2) You fit your regression model, then check the assumptions. If they were ok, then you plug in the new values for $Xi$'s i.e. $X1=22$, $X2=33$ in your fitted model to forecast  $Y_{T8}$. For instance, let's say you fit your regression model and estimated the regression coefficients as 0.5 and -2 then your model is $Y_t=0.5X1_t-2X2_t+\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is the error terms. Then the forecast for $Y_8$ would be $\hat{Y_8}=0.5(22)-2(33)$.

3) No, it is not mandatory.

If you decided to use the Arima model, then $X1$ and $X2$ would be the xreg argument the in the Arima function as explained in the package [forecast](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf).